# Turning Lists of Formulas Into Lists of Ordered Pairs

Tags: list-manipulation, programming

I'm working with a finite list of linear equations in some amount of variables. Say,

{2kx-3y,3y+2kz-x,2x+2y+2z,ky}

Is it possible for Mathematica to take this list and output a list of pairs where the elements of the ordered pairs correspond to the coefficients of the variables in my formula? So in the list above, 2kx-3y corresponds to (2k,-3,0), 3y+2kz-x corresponds to (-1,3,2k), etc., so that the output list should be the following

{(2k,-3,0),(-1,3,2k),(2,2,2),(0,k,0)}

This is not homework, I just am building a program in python and it needs this output list as input.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
lst = {2 k x - 3 y, 3 y + 2 k z - x, 2 x + 2 y + 2 z, k y};
```

You can use [`Coefficient`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Coefficient.html) as follows:

```
Flatten[Coefficient[#, {x, y, z}]] & /@ lst
```

> {{2 k, -3, 0}, {-1, 3, 2 k}, {2, 2, 2}, {0, k, 0}}

Answer (score 0):

One can also use `CoefficientArrays[]` (after post-processing with `Normal[]`, because sparse arrays are produced by default):

```
Normal[Last[CoefficientArrays[{2 k x - 3 y, 3 y + 2 k z - x, 2 x + 2 y + 2 z, k y},
                              {x, y, z}]]]
   {{2 k, -3, 0}, {-1, 3, 2 k}, {2, 2, 2}, {0, k, 0}}
```